# Show ip address when os boot

Tags: bash, networking, centos, boot

I want to make when CentOS start in init 3 to show me my ip addr, before log in.
For Example:

```
CentOS Realese 6.5(Final)
Kernel 2.6..
ip addr: 192.168.1.1
```

or something like that.

I make script which is:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr'
```

but, I don't know where I put it.

I try in rc.local (with "cat" and him path) but obviously it is not right place, or I make something wrong.
And I try in /etc/issue , but and there maybe I make something wrong.

Comment: You want your computer to show you this where exactly? At what part of the boot process? On what screen?

Comment: In init 3, when the os start before login, but in the same screen..

Comment: That isn't a full answer. At what point during boot? What else is on the screen where you want to show this? You do realize that until fairly late in the boot up process your computer will not actually have an IP address that it can confidently use, right?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to explain it, but I put a image . I think in this time on start, it has IP.

[image] : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9WT9Hi4AlqKSzBGZ0Z5dkE2Zzg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: So on the login prompt then? Ok.

Comment: it looks like you want to put the line `ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr'`  in your .bashrc file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this code into /etc/rc.d/rc.local and install banner application tho show BIG ip address

```html
#!/bin/sh
#
# This script will be executed *after* all the other init scripts.
# You can put your own initialization stuff in here if you don't
# want to do the full Sys V style init stuff.

SETCOLOR_SUCCESS="echo -en \\033[1;32m"
SETCOLOR_FAILURE="echo -en \\033[1;31m"
SETCOLOR_WARNING="echo -en \\033[1;33m"
SETCOLOR_NORMAL="echo -en \\033[0;39m"
SETCOLOR_BLUE="echo -en \\033[0;36m"

touch /var/lock/subsys/local

${SETCOLOR_BLUE}
IP=`/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'`
${SETCOLOR_NORMAL}
#IP=255.255.255.255
if [[ -z "${IP}" ]]; then
    ${SETCOLOR_FAILURE}
    echo "######################################################################"
    echo "##                                                                  ##"
    echo "##        Please setup networking and restart virtual machine!      ##"
    echo "##                                                                  ##"
    echo "######################################################################"
else
    ${SETCOLOR_WARNING}
    echo "Local IP is"
    COLUMNS=200 banner ${IP}
fi
${SETCOLOR_SUCCESS}
echo "Use root/password to login"
${SETCOLOR_NORMAL}
```

Answer (score 5):

On **CentOS 7** and **Debian 8** (and maybe other as well), just append the following line to `/etc/issue`

```
My IP address: \4
```

and that will resolve to the machine's IPv4 address.
If you have multiple network interfaces and you want to pick one specific, you can specify it with

```
My IP address: \4{eth0}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe `/etc/issue` can be made to display IP addresses by itself which means you are probably going to need to rewrite your `/etc/issue` at boot time and possibly force login to reload to see it or something else of that general sort.

Update for newer OS versions: see [PaoloC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2365724/paoloc)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41592571/258523).

Answer (score 0):

Refer to https://serverfault.com/a/594262/177172

I use the following (slightly modified):

```
#!/bin/sh
## https://serverfault.com/a/594262/177172

IPADDRS_TEXT="IP addresses of all external interfaces of this host:"
IPADDRS="$(hostname --all-ip-addresses)"

perl -i -p -0777 -e "s/^$IPADDRS_TEXT[^\n]*\n\n//m; s/$/\n$IPADDRS_TEXT $IPADDRS\n/ if length('$IPADDRS')>6" /etc/issue
```

Not sure where you can place this file on CentOS so that it is executed on interface/ip address change.